# How do I create a create a site template that includes customizations?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, site-template

I have a question for you all. I used a calendar and created some events in it. Then I used the filter webparts to filter the results between a start date and an end date. Then I saved the site as .wsp file. This whole customization is done in my standalone machine. Now I intend to use that .wsp file to create a template in my farm environment. So I uploaded the solution in the solutions gallery and activate the solution. Then I used that .wsp template to create a new subsite. The site is created but all the customization done through the SharePoint Designer wasn't working. Now why's that? Is it true that the customizations done through Designer won't work when the solution is deployed on some other environment?

Comment: What customizations specifically didn't come through?  Is it that the filters were no longer connected?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you updated some information to a calendar, added some filters and created the site template right?. Well if I’m not wrong the information you updated is not in the site template is in the site content database that's why the information is not showing on the other site because it’s using a different database, also if you already uploaded the site template, you could go to the list where the events are being stored create a list template (Remember to select the checkbox "Include Content".) and upload that list template to your new site deploy it and all the information should be there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the site template, be sure to select the checkbox "Include Content".

It shouldn't make any difference whether you made changes with SharePoint Designer or using the UI - the template should be the same.

Whichever way you set them up, it is possible that in a different farm you List references will not work in the web parts because the lists may have different GUIDs. Although these should be reset automatically, I have heard of cases where this went wrong if the GUID format was not correct in the template. Secondly, I am not sure that web part connections will be set up correctly in sites created from the template. You may need to set these up again manually, or do some development work on your .wsp to re-wire these.

Comment: Well I already did that but its not working!!! Why does the customizations don't attach? If u have noticed its the same in MOSS 2007. So is that a default functionality???

Comment: You are going to have to give us a bit more information to go on if you want more help. Which customizations? And go easy on the punctuation - it's giving me a headache ;-)

Comment: Hello, For example I used the Date Filter webpart to filter the events happening on a specific date and display the results on the same page. Its working perfectly but when I restore it on a different environment the connections made are lost. And as might know that the connections are made using Designer 2010. So I had to redo the connections once again on the other environment. Hope I am clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.